# SQL Server hang and then restart after preemptive_com_getadate wait type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We are facing issue on the SQL Server , SQL Server fetching data from Oracle 12c through linked server but at the time of fetching data from oracle then we receive preemptive_com_getdata wait type then sql server consume all available physical RAM and then hang and then restart

What is the cause of this ?

Comment: What about the amount of data you try to fetch from oracle?

Comment: There are different integration services running on this server and some are fetching few data but some are fetching 1 million rows at a time

Comment: and hang occurs when you fetch 1 millions row, right?